# Magento: Get Customer ID in Admin

Tags: magento, admin, magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9 I want to get the customerId of opened customer in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View`.

I tried like this:

```
$customer_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); //I saw here in Stackoverflow this
$customer = $customer_session->getCustomer();
$customerID = $customer->getId();
```

But I got a null.

I also tried with `$this->getId()` and `Mage::helper('customer')->getId()`, but neither worked.

How do achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the correct way is:

`$customerID = $this->getCustomer()->getId();`

Answer (score 0):

For admin we should use 'admin/session' for 'customer/session'

```
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session'); 
$userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();
$userEmail = $user->getUser()->getEmail();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I updated my question. I looking for the userId what's opened in the customer manager